# Why in my Procedure is not printing the correct value updated?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here my code for test:

```
PROCEDURE INCREASE(p_employee in number)
is
  V_salary   employees.salary%type;
BEGIN

  Select  salary into v_salary
  From employees where  employee_id = p_employee;

  if v_salary >= 15000 then
  Update employees set salary  =  v_salary + ((v_salary * 20)/100)  Where employee_id = p_employee;
    else 
    Update employees set salary  =  v_salary + ((v_salary * 10)/100)  Where employee_id = p_employee;

 end if;
 commit;


  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || v_name || '  ' || 'salary: ' || v_salary );
End;
```

When I run the procedure and printed to see the output, we see the result before the update:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCPGi.png)

When I see the salary for this user is already updated when I select the table Employees:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Sdc.png)

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include the data you've got in your EMPLOYEES table, and a test harness which shows how you're callilng this procedure along with the results you're getting. Based on [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d195f9b846d51bfdb2a9159a923682a2) I have to say that it appears your procedure is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not printing the updated value, you are printing the selected value. Your update changes the value of salary in the database, it does NOT change variable selected into. You need to [return](http://psoug.org/snippet.htm/UPDATE-with-RETURNING-clause_604.htm) clause of the update statement.  Moreover you don't need to select; this can be done in a single statement, except for setting up to variable and actually printing.

```
create or replace procedure increase(p_employee in number)
is
  v_salary   employees.salary%type;
begin

  update employees 
     set salary  =  case when salary >= 15000
                         then 1.2 * salary
                         else 1.1 * salary
                    end   
    where employee_id = p_employee
    return salary into v_salary; 

  commit;
  dbms_output.put_line('mesalao: ' || v_salary );
end;
```